# Static Redefine after reboot of embedded System C

Tags: c, variables, static, reset

I work on an embedded System - not a windows system.

I declare:

```
static uint_8 i = 0;
```

So i is defined 0 at start moment.

The question: After a reset is i redefined as 0 or does it get a junk information at the ram adress? E.g do I need to write a init function to redefine i as 0?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This depends on your runtime library (if any). If you have an existing runtime library, it will probably initialise your static data to zero on startup (before `main()`). However, some embedded systems may not have complete runtime library support so you may have to do this yourself.

Comment: thank you for making me _not_ look like a fool! I asked "do we have a runtime lib? cause a static should be redefined" - and no we dont have this lib in our system. So now i am on to write that init function!

Comment: Great, sounds fun. Been there! :)

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't have to. All static variables are guaranteed to be initialized to 0 when a program starts.

C standard ISO/IEC 9899:TC2 defines this in the following way.

> 6.2.4 Storage durations of objects
>   An object whose identifier is declared with external or internal linkage, or with the storage-class
>   specifier static has static storage duration. Its lifetime is the
>   entire execution of the program and its stored value is initialized
>   only once, prior to program startup.